# Property 'isError' does not exist on type 'Codec', when showing sudo events

Tags: polkadot-js

I try to implement [How do I get the Result of a Sudo event?](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/cookbook/tx#how-do-i-get-the-result-of-a-sudo-event) in a function shown below. It's mostly an exact copy from the cookbook with some boilerplate.

```js
export const sudo = async (
    api: ApiPromise,
    signer: KeyringPair,
    call: any,
): Promise<SubmittableResult> => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        const result = await api.tx.sudo.sudo(call).signAndSend(signer,
                                                           (result) =>
            {
                if (result.status.isInBlock || result.status.isFinalized) {
                  
                    //explain the error from the function executed by sudo
                    result.events
                        // We know this tx should result in `Sudid` event.
                        .filter(({ event }) => api.events.sudo.Sudid.is(event))
                        // We know that `Sudid` returns just a `Result`
                        .forEach(({ event : { data: [result] } }) => {
                            // Now we look to see if the extrinsic was actually successful or not...
                            if (result.isError) {
                                let error = result.asError;
                                if (error.isModule) {
                                    // for module errors, we have the section indexed, lookup
                                    const decoded = api.registry.findMetaError(error.asModule);
                                    const { docs, name, section } = decoded;

                                    console.log(`${section}.${name}: ${docs.join(' ')}`);
                                } else {
                                    // Other, CannotLookup, BadOrigin, no extra info
                                    console.log(error.toString());
                                }
                            }
                        });

                    resolve(result);
                } else if (result.status.isInvalid) {
                    reject(new Error(`Extrinsic isInvalid`));
                } else if (result.dispatchError) {
                    reject(new Error(`Dispatch error: ${result.dispatchError}`));
                } else if (result.internalError) {
                    reject(new Error(`Internal error: ${result.internalError}`));
                }
            });
    });
};
```

but get the following compilation error

```
 if (result.isError) {

 error TS2339: Property 'isError' does not exist on type 'Codec'.
```

When I use a [similar construct](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/cookbook/tx#how-do-i-get-the-decoded-enum-for-an-extrinsicfailed-event) for regular transactions, it works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking into it a bit, it seems that the `Sudid` event is not plainly a `RuntimeError`, maybe it was in the past but not anymore. It's an event with payload. You need to extract the actual `RuntimeError` from a payload called `sudoResult` from the `Sudid` events payload.

Sudid Event of the Events Enum of the `pallet_sudo`:
https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/e2caa813bfd2973e7a7a74aa5292433397dbc787/substrate/frame/sudo/src/lib.rs#L302-L306

Here is an adapted piece of code how to do it.

```ts
const unsubscribe = await api.tx.sudo
  .sudo(api.tx.balances.forceTransfer(user1, user2, amount))
  .signAndSend(keyring.createFromUri("//Alice"), ({ status, events }) => {
    switch (status.type) {
      case "Finalized":
      case "InBlock":
        {
          if (status.isInBlock) {
            console.log("Transaction included at blockHash", status.asInBlock);
          }

          events.forEach((record) => {
            if (api.events.sudo.Sudid.is(record.event)) {

              // NEW PART:
              if (record.event.data.sudoResult.isErr) {

                // SAME PART AS IN DOCS:
                let error = record.event.data.sudoResult.asErr;
                if (error.isModule) {
                  // for module errors, we have the section indexed, lookup
                  const decoded = api.registry.findMetaError(error.asModule);
                  const { docs, name, section } = decoded;

                  console.log(`${section}.${name}: ${docs.join(" ")}`);
                } else {
                  // Other, CannotLookup, BadOrigin, no extra info
                  console.log(error.toString());
                }
              }
              return record.event;
            }
          });
        }
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  });
```

The docs are surely outdated here, I will create a PR to make it work again.
Hope this helps.